# Laravel queue jobs timeout

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.8 job queue that frequently fails jobs due to this error:

```
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: A queued job has been attempted too many times. The job may have previously timed out.
```

And error on server:

```
Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: select * from jobs where ... for update)
```

It's only happening in production and when I'm trying to export a large database.

In my local, with wampserver everything fine.

My docker server is using nginx.

Here is my worker command: ( I have 8 worker )

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=export --tries=3 --memory=2048 --timeout=3600
```

Comment: Where is the ask?

Comment: Hi, my English is not good. I hope you will understand what I said. The ask is Has anyone run into the same problem? And how to solve it?. Thank you.

Comment: This happens when two processes are trying to write to the same database table at the same time

Comment: Thank for your answer. But how to prevent it from running same time? And why in local, using windows everything fine.

Comment: Your applications seems to contain long running queries that cause deadlocks. Do you have any idea how these deadlocks may have been caused?

Comment: With the current information, is impossible to know

Comment: @MaartenDev It happens when I'm trying exporting > 30k records.

Manuel. I will give you more information, what info you need to know?

Comment: Why do you have multiple workers exporting 30k records? There should be one right?

Comment: There a lot of users try to export in the same time.

Comment: Seems weird that deadlocks occur for read only export actions, are you modifying the table contents in another job?

Comment: No. Its happen when 'jobs' table in laravel update. You can see **(SQL: select * from jobs where ... for update)**